# Get Unique Values From A Search Query To Populate Search Filter Options

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I have a product search on my site that uses a sql query to grab the results.

For example:

```
$result=odbc_prepare($connection, "SELECT name, description, brand FROM item_catalog WHERE description LIKE $searchterm");
odbc_execute($result);
    $count = odbc_num_rows($result);
        if($count >= 1) {
            while($row = odbc_fetch_array($result)) {
                echo "<table cellspacing='7px' cellpadding='0' border='0'>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td style='vertical-align:top;line-height:0; display:none;'></td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['brand'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "</table>";
            }
        }
```

I want to be able to take the results of a search and populate a filter box with just the **unique** values from the brand field.  So, the user can filter the results based on the brand. I just want to place the unique brands in an unordered list and I'll have a checkbox next to each brand.

How do I grab just the unique brand values? I've played around with unique_array but couldn't get that to work.

Keep in mind, there will be more filters than just brand.  Potentially, 5-10 fields we will want to populate the filters for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DISTINCT` as in:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       brand
       FROM item_catalog
       WHERE description LIKE ?;
```

But the best thing you could do is normalizing the schema. Have a separate table with all the brands and just a foreign key to that table in `item_catalog`.

Comment: That would populate a filter box with ALL of the brands.  I just want the unique brands that are returned from a users search query.

Comment: Just add the `WHERE` clause then. See the edit. And also note, that you should better use parameterized queries.

Comment: i guess I was trying to avoid executing multiple queries every time a user performs a search. Especially when I have to populate 5-10 filter boxes.

Comment: Why? If it is because of performance, then keep in mind, that the DBMS is made for such tasks and performs very well, when the schema is well designed and indexed. But of course this also depends on the amount of data and the connection to the DBMS...